# Push Notification using Urban Airship in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am implementing Push Notification for my android app using Urban Airship. I started the setup as per the documentation http://urbanairship.com/docs/android-client-push.html 
However can any body post me any Tutorial to get started with push notification. I tried running the Push Sample application from urban airship but not receiving any notifications.

Can any one point me in right direction(tutorial) to restart it from scratch again.

thanks, in advance...

Comment: I actually work at Urban Airship - are you running into any errors? If you add more information, I can probably help out

Comment: To follow on what Emile said, the best place to start looking for issues is the logcat output when you start up your app. The most common problems are missing entries in the AndroidManifest.xml, or issues where the configuration in the application's config files don't match what's set up in the UA application. If you want to send the logcat information, manifest, and config file to support, we can help you find the issue.

Comment: I am able to get the push notification from the Urban Airship, but when I am clicking on the push notification, it is not opening my app. Can anybody help me, what I need to do ?